# Create txt file in every subfolder

Tags: windows, cmd

I am running windows server 2003. I have a directory that contains hundreds of sub-folders. I want to auto create txt file in each subfolder that will list all the files in that subfolder. Some folders uses special/Chinese characters. How can I do this with CMD? or any other language or tool

Comment: This is possible, but the code is awfully horrible. Why not WScript (VBS)?

Comment: Well any language is fine so can you tell me the code? or tool to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using batch:

```
@echo off
chcp 65001 >nul
for /r "C:\your\dir" %%d in (.) do dir /a:-d "%%~fd" > "%%~dpnd\dirlist.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `FileSystemObject` of Windows Scripting contains everything you need, but you'll need to write a bit of VBScript code to plug it together:

1. Create and assign an instance of `FileSystemObject` using something like `Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`.
2. `For Each Folder In fso.GetFolder(...).SubFolders` iterates through all subfolders. For deep iteration, use recursion.
3. There is also `Files` which lists all files of a `Folder`.
4. `CreateTextFile` does what it promises, and also has a unicode option.

If you do not need deep iteration, a CMD solution would be probably shorter, though I suspect you will run into Unicode problems.

Comment: I'm not aware of any, no. To me this looks a bit too specialized. OTOH, the resulting VBScript is something between 5 and 8 lines of code. You might find acquiring some programming practice useful, or look for somebody willing to glue this together *and* reply to potential change requests on your behalf...